# Matplotlib colormap value conversion

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have the following code:

```
def _cmap2rgb(cmap, step):
    from matplotlib import cm
    return getattr(cm, cmap)(step)
```

Which will convert a color map and return the RGBA value for a given step between 0 to 255.

The result of say:

```
 >>> _cmap2rgb('Blues', 0)

 (0.9686274528503418, 0.9843137264251709, 1.0, 1.0)
```

I was expecting the RGB values to be between 0 and 255.  Is there a way to convert it to those values?

So the output is like this:

```
 (0,0,255,1)
```

Where the 4th value is the alpha.

I wanted to make sure of this, but I think I just need to multiply my values by 255 to get the right value to ensure of a 1:1 color match?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. You could for instance do `tuple(int(x*255) if i<3 else x for i,x in enumerate(a))`, if `a` is your original tuple.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for confirming what I thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to multiply those values by 255. Actually, every cmap has parameter 'bytes':

> bytes : bool
>       If False (default), the returned RGBA values will be floats in the
>       interval `[0, 1]` otherwise they will be uint8s in the interval
>       `[0, 255]`.

```
def _cmap2rgb(cmap, step):
    from matplotlib import cm
    return getattr(cm, cmap)(step, bytes=True)
```

Comment: If you need to encode the values as JSON, just be aware that the values returned from the function are of type np.int, not int, so you need to cast them before converting them using the ```json``` library.